# What does *unspecified* means in C++ typedef statement?

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef, declaration

I see statements like

> typedef *unspecified*       value_type;
>
> typedef *unspecified*       reference;

in the declaration of Boost::multi_array class.

```
    namespace boost {

template <typename ValueType, 
          std::size_t NumDims, 
          typename Allocator = std::allocator<ValueType> >
class multi_array {
public:
// types:
  typedef ValueType                             element;
  typedef *unspecified*                         value_type;
  typedef *unspecified*                         reference;
  typedef *unspecified*                         const_reference;
  typedef *unspecified*                         difference_type;
  typedef *unspecified*                         iterator;
  typedef *unspecified*                         const_iterator;
  typedef *unspecified*                         reverse_iterator;
  typedef *unspecified*                         const_reverse_iterator;
  typedef multi_array_types::size_type          size_type;
  typedef multi_array_types::index              index;
  typedef multi_array_types::index_gen          index_gen;
  typedef multi_array_types::index_range        index_range;
  typedef multi_array_types::extent_gen         extent_gen;
  typedef multi_array_types::extent_range       extent_range;
  typedef *unspecified*                         storage_order_type;
```

what does the *unspecified* mean here? Is this a C++11 standard?

Comment: Is this copied from documentation rather than compiling headers? That doesn't look like valid C++ to me, but does look like documentation which is trying to tell you the typedef exists without telling you the real name of the underlying type which maye be subject to change in the future.

Comment: Just to emphisize Stewart's comment: if you will open multy_array.hpp you won't find there any "*unspecified*" tokens. There are references to a base class that depends on teplate parameters.

Comment: yes, I copied it from the documentation rather than the code.

Comment: This is only documentation. It means that there is a typedef called `value_type`, but that it is unspecified what the source type is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm assuming this in documentation, not compilable code, since it isn't compilable.

It's common to do this to indicate that the typedef is available for use, but the type that it aliases depends on the implementation and isn't considered part of the public interface.

In this case, the compilable header file contains declarations along the lines of:

```
typedef typename super_type::value_type value_type;
```

where the aliased type is defined in a base class. Digging deeper, that in turn comes from another base class, and the actual type is deeply buried in the implementation details, with different definitions depending on how many dimensions the array has; this particular type is `ValueType` for a one-dimensional array, and `multi_array<ValueType,NumDims-1>` for higher dimensions.

Answer (score 8):

That looks like it's copied from [this documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html#multi_array). `*unspecified*` just means, that it is totally irrelevant to you and that it's an implementation detail. Don't look further into it, just acknowledge, that the typedefs are there.

Answer (score 2):

I just opened the multi_array.hpp header, and (as expected) it has no such typedefs, but it looks like this :

```
    template<typename T, std::size_t NumDims,typename Allocator>
    class multi_array :
        public multi_array_ref<T,NumDims>
    {
      typedef multi_array_ref<T,NumDims> super_type;
    public:
      typedef typename super_type::value_type value_type;
      typedef typename super_type::reference reference;
      typedef typename super_type::const_reference const_reference;
      typedef typename super_type::iterator iterator;
      typedef typename super_type::const_iterator const_iterator;
      typedef typename super_type::reverse_iterator reverse_iterator;
      typedef typename super_type::const_reverse_iterator const_reverse_iterator;
      typedef typename super_type::element element;
      typedef typename super_type::size_type size_type;
      typedef typename super_type::difference_type difference_type;
      typedef typename super_type::index index;
      typedef typename super_type::extent_range extent_range;
   // ...
```

If you are reading the [reference pages for boost::multi_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html), then it means that you should use that typedef, instead of your own type. I guess those typedefs should be really used when writing template classes.

Answer (score 1):

No. It means that a specific implementation may typedef it to be whatever it wants. This is in a specification- not actual compilable C++.

Answer (score 0):

unspecified is an empty struct defined in the boost::units::detail namespace.

It is used just as a place holder return type in a parent class (think inheritance) taking advantage of the fact that it can be overloaded in any future derived class with appropriate return type.
There could be several other use in generic programming. 
I will keep on adding here as and when I find out more examples.